# Jquery Tabs: spinner option not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I need an ajax animation while the remote page is loaded in tabs.

I am using

```
$('#tabs2').tabs({ spinner: ''<img src="../../Content/images/Jquery/spinner.gi'' });
```

Even `$('#tabs2').tabs({ spinner: 'Loading..' });` also doesn't works ...

Though the tab functionality is working but the animation is not working ...

I am using JQuery theme roller files. Your help is much appreciated.  Many Thanks

Comment: is this the actual code? what is this: ''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry problem solved. I Put a `<span>` tag in the tabs. Found the solution in Jquery support discussions. http://docs.jquery.com/Discussion

e.g.

```
<li><a href="../URL">**<span>Text to display in Tabs</span></a></li>
<li><a href="tabdiv">**<span>Text to display in Tabs</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Why do you need those asterisks?

Comment: yeah, what's up with the asterisks?

Answer (score 3):

If spinner doesn't work for you (it doesn't for me), try this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ 
                beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.panel.text('Retrieving data...');
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is currently the correct answer. The spinner option was deprecated in version 1.9 (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7134)

Answer (score 2):

This first code snippet as posted, looks incorrect. It should be:

```
$('#tabs2').tabs({ spinner: '<img src="../../Content/images/Jquery/spinner.gif"/>' });
```

The second snippet should work just fine assuming that "#tabs2" refers to the container tab and not one of the individual tabs.

Please edit your question and post the associated HTML for the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The spinner option of the jquery.ui tabs is only used when loading remote content with ajax.
Are you sure you're using ajax mode and not simply showing and hiding existing content on your page with tabs ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what is the answer, so once again, if somebody couldn't figure out as well.

Not the content of the tab is being replaced during load but the tab title. 
All you need to do is putting tab title into span tags

before:

```
<ul >
 <li><a href="link.html" >Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

after

```
<ul >
 <li><a href="link.html" ><span>Users</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The tab header must be surrounded with span, as you can see 
Users becomes `<span>Users</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a  around the text of the tab links fixes the problem. Sumanta's solution is correct, but I'm not sure you need the two asterisk symbols that are in there.