# jquery ui tabs problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show 'loading' when the tab is loading... cause the content is coming with ajax.
Heres my code

```
$('#tab').tabs({
            spinner: 'Loading'
        });
```

The content comes just fine but it never shows "Loading"... at all

Am I Blind or Im doign something wrong?... Have tried IE and Firefox.

Comment: Looks OK - what's your HTML like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is here:

[Jquery Tabs: spinner option not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008110/jquery-tabs-spinner-option-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for that... That sucks though, cause Im using asp.net mvc
HTML.ActionLink... so how am I supposed to add a <span>?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it html to show... should be something like:

```
$('#tab').tabs({
        spinner: '<img src="/images/spinner.gif" />'
});
```

[**From the docs:**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-spinner)

The HTML content of this string is shown in a tab title while remote content is loading. Pass in empty string to deactivate that behavior.
Code examples

Initialize a tabs with the spinner option specified.

```
$('.selector').tabs({ spinner: 'Retrieving data...' });
```

Get or set the spinner option, after init.

```
//getter
var spinner = $('.selector').tabs('option', 'spinner');
//setter
$('.selector').tabs('option', 'spinner', 'Retrieving data...');
```